# Close Button (right top X) to act similar to control?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

C#, ASP.NET, JS

I have this pop up opened where employees work on different clients.
Once they are done they click on a button and a few proceses run before actually closing the pop up window.

What I want to achieve is the same thing when they hit the X top right button of the screen.

I've tried this:

.aspx.

```
window.onclose = closePage;
```

.js.

```
function closePage() { 
__doPostBack('XXXX', '');
}
```

.cs

```
//In Page_Load
if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "XXXX")
       {
           //desired code.
       }
```

It's definetely not firing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.net runs at server level and doesn't inherently "know" when the site is closed by the user. To achieve what you want you need to use ASP.NET Ajax.

There is a good article here;

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/03/07/asp-net-ajax-in-depth-application-events.aspx